# Decrypting with openssl enc

Tags: bash, encryption, openssl

I'm encrypting data with `openssl enc` but I'm getting a lot of garbage data when I do it in the default binary mode; but everything works fine in ascii mode.

Given the following definitions:

```
iv=1968879c2ae5b6e4bdd2823b5e9fa54a
enc() { key=$1; shift; openssl enc -K "$key" -iv "$iv" -aes-256-ctr -p -nosalt "$@"; }
dec() { key=$1; shift; openssl enc -d -K "$key" -iv "$iv" -aes-256-ctr -p -nosalt "$@"; }
```

...running

```
enc 33 -a <<<test123 | dec 33 -a | hexdump -C
```

...correctly emits:

```
00000000  6b 65 79 3d 33 33 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  |key=330000000000|
00000010  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  |0000000000000000|
*
00000040  30 30 30 30 0a 69 76 20  3d 31 39 36 38 38 37 39  |0000.iv =1968879|
00000050  43 32 41 45 35 42 36 45  34 42 44 44 32 38 32 33  |C2AE5B6E4BDD2823|
00000060  42 35 45 39 46 41 35 34  41 0a 74 65 73 74 31 32  |B5E9FA54A.test12|
00000070  33 0a                                             |3.|
00000072
```

Whereas doing the same without `-a` emits binary garbage; using `base64` to make that output printable,

```
enc 33 <<<test123 | dec 33 | hexdump -C
```

...emits as output a base64 encoding of a much longer string than `test123`:

```
00000000  6b 65 79 3d 33 33 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  |key=330000000000|
00000010  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30  |0000000000000000|
*
00000040  30 30 30 30 0a 69 76 20  3d 31 39 36 38 38 37 39  |0000.iv =1968879|
00000050  43 32 41 45 35 42 36 45  34 42 44 44 32 38 32 33  |C2AE5B6E4BDD2823|
00000060  42 35 45 39 46 41 35 34  41 0a 2f 5a 77 fb 7a 37  |B5E9FA54A./Zw.z7|
00000070  ca 60 43 f6 17 ce 13 da  d8 40 f9 78 30 6f 44 60  |.`C......@.x0oD`|
00000080  fc b4 63 05 69 38 45 b3  19 8c 04 bc 79 0e 0e de  |..c.i8E.....y...|
00000090  10 3f d3 9e 19 d6 8c 93  67 3b 20 5a 9f cd c2 3f  |.?......g; Z...?|
000000a0  76 36 2a 71 31 c0 a0 49  fc 4a c0 aa b0 b1 c7 e2  |v6*q1..I.J......|
000000b0  1c c5 0a 54 b7 d9 e4 b4  8a 2e 05 4a f4 3b 9c 01  |...T.......J.;..|
000000c0  37 fc 0e 69 a8 86 f7 cd  21 a3 2e 94 0a 1f fa b3  |7..i....!.......|
000000d0  07 61 26 d9 b4 e0 b6 6f  3a e6 72 e8              |.a&....o:.r.|
000000dc
```

Comment: A few asides: `key=$1; shift` and then use `"$@"` at the end; that way you pass through all extra command-line arguments without breaking their quoting. (`key=` rather than `KEY=` is per http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- all-caps names are used for variables meaningful to the shell itself, lowercase names are reserved for application use and guaranteed not to have side effects on behavior of POSIX-compliant shells).

Comment: Your `enc.bash` and `denc.bash` given here are identical. Is that a copy/paste error?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you, that's way easier to remember than googling `"${@:2}"` every time I want to exclude the first argument. I changed the variable names in my scripts, though I'll leave it here for future viewers. Now to fix all my bash scripts...

Comment: @CharlesDuffy And yes, there's only a 2 letter difference so I copied the original twice and forgot to make the change. Fixed now.

Comment: BTW, I'd personally write a reproducer as given in https://ideone.com/2HMP9t; no need for separate scripts where functions will do. Also, the `key=` and `iv=` outputs are probably pertinent, no? Certainly shows that the key isn't being parsed the way you expect.

Comment: See my proposed rewrite of the question at https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/be53b4533071c8e846ebe38a17cb1194; intent being that that gets us closer to copy+paste to reproduce, whereas to follow it as currently given one needs to actually create files.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Your rewrite looks good. You can put it in an edit if you like (so your name shows up as the editor) otherwise I can do it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Why do you say the key isn't being parsed as expected?

Comment: That was a misunderstanding on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-p` option of `openssl` that outputs the key and IV, gives you these garbage bytes.

If you remove this `-p` option from the `enc()` function, that'll work.

With `-a` option, `openssl` skips non base64 string (i.e. the key and IV info) from the input, this is the reason why it works.

Examples:

```
echo test123 | openssl enc -K 33 -iv 0 -aes-256-ctr -p -nosalt | openssl enc -d -K 33 -iv 0 -aes-256-ctr -p -nosalt  
# -> fail
echo test123 | openssl enc -K 33 -iv 0 -aes-256-ctr -p -nosalt -a | openssl enc -d -K 33 -iv 0 -aes-256-ctr -p -nosalt -a
# -> OK
echo test123 | openssl enc -K 33 -iv 0 -aes-256-ctr -nosalt | openssl enc -d -K 33 -iv 0 -aes-256-ctr -p -nosalt
# -> OK
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I guess I assumed that extra information would be output on `stderr`.